# Where are Ethernet Settings stored?

Tags: settings, networking

There is [a good post about where Android Settings are stored](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40719/where-are-android-settings-stored). 
The following screenshot shows where Wi-Fi settings are stored.

[image]

Where are Ethernet Settings stored?

Comment: There is a directory `/data/misc/ethernet` noted [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core.git/+/8b32c30b92be6914da2dca23089473c4f37adfb9/rootdir/init.rc#260) as well as in my device's init.rc. However, it is empty and I do not know what purpose  it serves. Which Android device are you using?

Comment: [Related](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/77474)

Comment: @Firelord It is a custom device running Android 4.2.  I have just checked its init.rc, and did not find any entry for Ethernet.   I thought there was a standard directory structure for all Android devices supporting Ethernet.  It does not look so.

Comment: @Firelord That directory is empty due to your device not supporting Ethernet. It probably gets created whether the device supports Ethernet or not, and is filled only in the former case. Since OP's OS seems to be not stock, it may be that the author removed the setting that created the **ethernet** folder altogether.

Comment: [How to make Ethernet work on Android over OTG?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/225741/218526)